# C++ - Does LoadLibrary() actually link to the library?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks and hate manually linking DLLs. I found the `LoadLibrary()` function, and am wondering if it works like a `.a` or `.lib` file would. Does this function work like that? If not, what can I do programming-wise (if anything) to link a DLL without having to link a DLL by doing the `Project < Build options < Linker settings < add < ...` method?

Comment: You don't link to DLLs at link-time and you don't load static libraries at runtime.

Comment: @chris: Actually, you *do* link to dynamic libraries at compile-time (even if just to stubs, or any other specific loader magic). Otherwise how would your program be able to access the symbols it contains? ;)

Comment: @syam, Well, you don't really have to do anything special to worry about it at least.

Comment: @chris: "*you don't really have to do anything special*" => Apparently, specifying `-lfoobar` on the compiler's command line to link to `libfoobar.so` (or any Windows equivalent, you get the picture) seems to be "something special" for OP (and a burden, at that). But I'm sure he'll soon change his mind when he sees how much work `LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress` (resp. `dlopen/dlsym`) really means. ;)

Answer (score 4):

`LoadLibrary` loads the requested library (and all the libraries it needs) into your process' address space. In order to access any of the code/data in that library, you need to find out the code or data address in the newly loaded region of memory. You need to use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The difference between this process and adding a library during build time is that for build-time library the  compiler prepares a list of locations that refer to a given function, linker puts that list into .exe, and run-time linker loads the library, does the equivalent of `GetProcAddress` for the function name and places the address into all locations that the compiler marked.

When you don't have this automated support, you have to declare a pointer to function, call `GetProcAddress` yourself, and assign the returned value to  your pointer to function. You can then call the function like any other C function (note "C" part - the above process is complicated by  name mangling when you use C++, so make use of `extern "C"`)

Answer (score 0):

`LoadLibrary()` loads a DLL at runtime. Normaly you link when you compile the EXE, and link the DLLs like a static library at this time. If you need to load libraries dynamically at runtime, you use `LoadLibrary()`.

For example when you implement a pluginsystem, is this usefull, as you don't know the libraries beforehand.

Comment: No. With th eproject settings oyu know exactly which DLL you are attaching to your program. the DLL is automatically loaded when your program starts. Using LoadLibrary measn you have to do this manually in the code, and also don't know which symbols are available.

Answer (score 0):

Not how it works at all. `LoadLibrary` is used to load a "at compile time unknown" DLL - such as program extensions/plugins or "This DLL for SSE, that DLL for non-SSE" based on "what can the hardware do - one could also consider having a DLL per connection type to email servers or something like that, so that the email program doesn't have to "carry" all the different variants, when only one is used for any particular email address.

Further, to use a DLL that has been loaded this way, you need to use `GetProcAddress` to get the address of the functions in the DLL. This is very different from linking the DLL into the project at buildtime, where functions simply appear "automagically" by help of the system loader functions that load the DLL's that are added to the project at build-time.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to static or dynamic library linking, `LoadLibrary` doesn't make the library's symbols directly available to your program. You need to call `GetProcAddress` at runtime to get a pointer to the functions you want to call.

As @Devolus mentioned, this is a good way to implement plugin systems and/or to access optional components. However, since the symbols are not available to your program in a transparent way, this is not really practical for ordinary usage.